# Как сделать запись и чтение в файл Kotlin?

Tags: android, файлы, kotlin, filewriter, readfile

Как в 2022 нормально использовать файл, я все форумы пролистал и все не работает
Есть такой колд, но он тоже не работает:

```
fun file(){
var sfi = openFileOutput("notes.txt", MODE_APPEND)
sfi.write("\"first note\",\"note\"".toByteArray())
sfi.close()
val namenotes = openFileInput("notes.txt")
println(namenotes)
}
```

Comment: И этот вопрос закроют. А потому что нет телепатов знать, что у вас не так. Может вы в манифесте не прописали, может в вашем случае нужно использовать Context.MODE_PRIVATE при открытии. Вам  же давали ссылку где написано "On devices that run Android 7.0 (API level 24) or higher, unless you pass the Context.MODE_PRIVATE file mode into openFileOutput(), a SecurityException occurs." У вас же код и приложение - вам виднее посмотреть что где появляется в дебаге

Comment: Не очень понятен ваш вопрос, что именно не работает в приведенном вами коде? Этот код выбрасывает исключение? Молчаливо не пишет в файл? Молчаливо не читает из файла? Задайте вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокусирован на конкретной проблеме. Сейчас не совсем ясно, как именно отвечать на ваш вопрос.

Comment: ну и смотреть нужно не run, а logcat. И можно в try catch обернуть посмотреть тоже - дебаггер не очень хорошо на бряках останавливается. Это лучше нашего гадания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В языке Kotlin есть удобная функция [`writeText()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/write-text.html) для записи строки в файл, например:

```kotlin
File(filesDir, "notes.txt").writeText("Hello World")
```

И [`readText()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-text.html) для чтения строки из файла, например:

```kotlin
val content = File(filesDir, "notes.txt").readText()
```

Comment: спасибо большое