# Как сделать запись и чтение json файл в android kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Нигде не могу найти нормальную информацию о том, как осуществить запись и чтение из json файла в android, использую язык kotlin. Мне достаточно самого простого примера.

Comment: С чем конкретно возникла проблема: чтение файла, парсинг json, запись файла? Json-файл такой же файл, как и любой другой, почему вопрос именно про json? Уточните конкретную проблему, с которой вы столкнулись. Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку "править" под вопросом.

Comment: Какую библиотеку надо использовать или что-либо ещё, нигде не могу найти примера как сделать запись в json файл и чтение от туда же. Да даже нормально нету где посмотреть как сделать запись в обычный файл

Comment: Возможные дубликаты вопроса: 1) [Куда положить файлы, чтобы их можно было читать и видоизменять?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1442833) 2) [Как сделать запись и чтение в файл Kotlin?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1469368)

Answer (score 0):

В языке Kotlin есть удобная функция [`writeText()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/write-text.html) для записи строки в файл, например:

```kotlin
File(filesDir, "file.txt").writeText("Hello World")
```

И [`readText()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-text.html) для чтения строки из файла, например:

```kotlin
val content = File(filesDir, "file.txt").readText()
```

Если сохраняйте файлы во внутреннее хранилище [`filesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) или [`cacheDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getCacheDir()), то их можно использовать только внутри вашего приложения.

Посмотрите в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage), какие способы хранения данных есть в Андроид, чтобы выбрать наиболее подходящий для вашей задачи.

Comment: А в какой папке находится этот файл, после записи? Нигде не могу его найти.

Comment: Файл сохраняется в `/data/data/com.example/files/file.txt` в случае `filesDir` или в `/data/data/com.example/cache/file.txt` в случае `cacheDir`, где `com.example` — имя пакета вашего приложения. Доступ до `/data/data/com.example` есть только у вашего приложения с именем пакета `com.example`. В дебаг режиме перейти в эту директорию можно с помощью `adb`, выполнив следующие команды: `adb shell`, `run-as com.example`.